# React Native Image not Displaying

Tags: react-native, image, remote-server

I have a project of react native as from api request I have got some image url

`https://someserver.blob.core.windows.net/project/logo_19293871923`

But there is no png and jpg extention in it some react native image not showing through uri like

`<Image source={{uri: 'https://someserver.blob.core.windows.net/project/logo_19293871923'}} style={style.image} />`

Can any one help

I have no idea what to do

Comment: the URL is broken

Comment: It is a demo url as I get from azure storage